# Microsoft Edge Smart Mirror on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: smart-home, microsoft-windows-iot

I've been reading this blog about building a *magic mirror* with Windows IoT:

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/31/magic-mirror-hosted-web-app/

Now, with the Pi setup, a Windows 7 machine, VS 2017 with Win 10 SDK and having pulled the source from github:

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/magic-mirror-demo

I'm finding that I can't build the solution in VS 17.

I opened the `Magic Mirror UWP App.sln`, changed the target platform to x64 but can't find the option to change the debugging target "Local machine".

When I build the solution everything builds correctly, but running it gives me this error:

*Unable to start debugging. The startup project cannot be launched. Ensure that the correct project is set as the startup project. The startup project can be changed by selecting 'Set as Start Project' command from the right click menu in Solution Explorer.*

However, of course, I have set the start up project to be the only project in the solution.

What am I doing wrong?